# Insert Data from Windows Form to a html Website in C# and get the output

Tags: c#, html

I am doing a project in which I have to make a windows application that will have some texboxes and checkboxes and these has to be filled by the user. I want to use this information and to automatically fill some fields in a Website when I click on a button, in my windows form.

I'm quite new to the subject and I have searched and found some ways that maybe I can do it, but I'm not sure how to do it. I heard about Web Client, Web Request and Web Response, and also HTML Agility Pack. The site is http://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvgis/apps4/pvest.php#.

I want to fill some of these fields and checkboxes with the information that I have in my Windows Form, and then click the calculate button and save the output. What is the best way to do that? I'm programming in C#.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: **automatically fill some fields in a Website** Website opened in a browser of some other user ? Or is it the same user who is running the windows application ?

Comment: Is this meant to visibly happen in a web browser external to the application?  A web browser control within the application?  Should it happen invisibly in a "headless" web browser?  Can it be done simply with raw HTTP requests/responses without involving a web browser at all?  There's a lot that can go into this, depending on exactly what you're trying to achieve.  Start by reverse-engineering what the actual website is doing when you perform this operation.  What happens that needs to be replicated in your code?  If you just want to interact with a browser, look up "browser automation".

Comment: The website doesn't need to be opened. But I need some information that I have to get from the website. For instance, the user fills some textboxes in my application (like the location, month of the year, slope and others), and then the application need to insert that information in the website and hit the calculate button in the website, in order to get the data from there. All of this with no need for the user to open the website, the application should do this automatically for him. Other way to do this is to create a database, but is not viable.

Sorry if I haven't explained myself right